# JavaScript removing price, but not removing text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, if you click on "Item-Card" then it takes the prices and "shows" it and the item-card goes red. If you click it again (the item card), then it goes back to white and removes that "price" from showing. So, I added basically same thing, just with "item name" in my eyes it works the same way, but if you re-click it, it doesn't remove the item.

JavaScript

```
var totalCoins = 0;
var showItem;
function calculateTotal() {
    totalCoins = 0;
    showItem;

    $(".selected-item").each(function() {
        var value = Number(prices2[$(this).find("img").attr("title")]);
        var naaaaame = $(this).find("img").attr("title");
        totalCoins += value;
        showItem = $("#items").html($("#items").html() + "<div class="+naaaaame+">"+naaaaame+" - "+value+" Coins</div>");
    });
    $("#coins-amt").text(numberWithCommas(totalCoins));
    if (totalCoins == 0) {
        $('#withdraw-button').addClass('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#withdraw-button').removeClass('disabled');
        $('#withdraw-button').removeClass('enabled');
    }
}
```

JavaScript click card

```
    $(".item-card").mousedown(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("red lighten-1 white-text selected-item");
        calculateTotal();
    });
```

JavaScript Create Card

```
$("#inventory").html($("#inventory").html() + "<li class='col 2' style='padding:1%;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px'><div class='card item-card waves-effect waves-light' style='margin:0%;height:295px;width:295.438px' id='" + item.id + "'><div class='iteam' style='text-decoration: underline;text-align: left'>"+item.naame+"</div><div class='condition' style='text-align: left;text-size:13px'>"+item.condition+"</div><div class='center-align' style='padding:6%'><img title=\"" + item.name + "\" draggable='false' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/" + item.iconurl + "/200fx200'><div class 'floatvalue'>Float: 0.11503319442272186<div class='bitskinscomp' style='font-weight: normal;font-size:12px'>"+message+"</div><div class='buyer-price center-align'>"+numberWithCommas(item.price)+" Coins</li></div></div>");
```

HTML

```
<div class="itemcart" id="items" style="position:relative;top:-120px;left:350px">Items</div>
<span id="status"></span>
</div>
<div class="container center" id="inv_container" style="margin-top:2%">
```

Comment: So we suppose to find out the issue by *reading* you code? Can't you give us a working demo ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't have a working demo, but I can try to make a gif.

Comment: I hope you can understand what I mean :D: https://gyazo.com/6c9f7f852bfce33011f9614f82387a17

Comment: Try `$("#items div:last").remove()` at your `if` condition.

Comment: Nope, sadly doesn't work. If I add "multiple" keys then it adds that text and if I start "removing" them some of the text will be there.

Comment: Here's what it does now: https://gyazo.com/c991835c227878fb964cf76641f59a46

Comment: Then remove them all. Use this `<div class='"+naaaaame+" item-price'>` and `$("#items .item-price").remove()`.

Comment: I think that, adding this part to the "if", it's not good. It will only remove "text" if button balance = 0, so if it's not 0, example you have 2 items and remove one, then it's not going to remove the text.

Comment: Well, as I said, its hard to *guess* the issue w/o a demo. Your problem seems to be simple, with a demo this question would be already answered  this far.

Comment: Hmm, there is no other code what could help I could add it here for sure. I'll edit first post add a bit more JavaScript

Comment: I believe a simple demo with your code could be easily done in 5 minutes in jsfiddle.com. There we can see your html and javascript working togheter, as well debug the code and give you right answer.

Comment: It's harder to help out with code? :(, we could use join.me if you would like to though.

Comment: Post the related html too.

Comment: Added, there's nothing though :D

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ps0zzfsa/

Comment: Maybe I did wrong something or idk. I can't get it working. It prints out item, but if I click again it doesn't remove it, and if I click again it does nothing, if I click 2nd time then it's "clickable" again.

Comment: @OlafMudj unless you put your code into a jsfiddle so we can see the problem properly you're unlikely to get a helpful answer. The reason being, because we'd just be guessing. 

It's simply a case of copying and pasting your code into the relevant sections in a jsfiddle. Post the link when you're done and we'll look at it.

Comment: @kanecheshire that is what I'm trying to say. Questions like this usually gets answered in first 10 min with a properly demo.

Comment: Sorry mate, I give up.

Comment: Tried to make fiddle, code didn't started working in there. Hmm.. It would help then, if I will give website URL?

Comment: @OlafMudj if it haves the same problem you've posted here, so probably yes, it would help.